# Need help in Google Analytics tool on a Windows 10 app that uses Ionic 2

Tags: android, angularjs, google-analytics, ionic2, windows-10-mobile

I am using Ionic 2 with Angular 2 as my base. Can anyone suggest me a good analytics tool that can be used that can work for all 3 mobile platforms i.e. Windows, iOS, & Android.

I did check Google Analytics but for some reason it did not work well with Windows 10 app. Is there any other tool that can help me on this.

In case you think Google Analytics is the tool to go for how do I go about using it.

Answer (score 0):

We are using [Google firebase](https://firebase.google.com/) for our analytics with Google big query to track the custom events for Android and IOS apps. [Ionic provides plugin to integrate with firebase](http://ionicframework.com/docs/native/firebase/). Its very simple to integrate and use firebase with Ionic. Other than analytics you can use firebase for authentication, storage and database also.

Note : We never worked with windows 10 platform

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes Ionic has a plugin to integrate firebase but that's for iOS and Android only. My major problem is Windows 10 platform. I need a solution for that platform the most.